# Meteor.js accounts-google get clientId and secret

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using the accounts-google package for oAuth in my meteor app. I want to grab the clientId and secret (apparently stored in the meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration mongo collection), but am unsure how to do so. Any help would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code snippet :

```
const googleServiceConfig = Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.findOne({
  service: 'google',
});
console.log(googleServiceConfig.clientId, googleServiceConfig.secret);
```